# How to change this function to display one result?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that shows all matches that have "20 pack" in the json database. Is there a way to manipulate this function to just search and stop after the first match. The database is in price ascending order hence the first result will be the cheapest.

```
 function displayMatches() {
    const searchText = '20 pack';
    const searchUrl = document.querySelector('.custom-select').value;
    const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, searchUrl, name);

      const html = matchArray.map(place => {
        const regex = new RegExp(searchText);
        const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${searchText}</span>`);
             var shop = place.url.replace(/(centra)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
             var shop1 = place.url.replace(/(tesco)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
             var shop2 = place.url.replace(/(aldi)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
             var shop3 = place.url.replace(/(lidl)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
             var shop4 = place.url.replace(/(supervalu)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
        return `
            <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank">
                <li>
                    <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)} <br><br><sup>${shop} ${shop1} ${shop2} ${shop3} ${shop4}</sup></span>
                    <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100">

                </li>
            </a>

        `;
      }).join('') || '<li> No Searches Found </li>';
      suggestions.innerHTML = html; 
    };
```

And my find matches function is

```
function findMatches(wordToMatch, searchUrl, name) {
    const regEx = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
    return name.filter(place => {
        return regEx.test(place.name) && place.url.startsWith(searchUrl);
    });
}
```

Comment: Change `const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, searchUrl, name);` to `const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, searchUrl, name)[0];`

Comment: Garbriele, I tried that one and it didn't work

Comment: and can you give a sample `name` contents ?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: i meant the `name` parameter your pass to `findMatches`. Some sample data for it. But there was an error in my previous comment, your `matchArray` needs to be an array so change it to `const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, searchUrl, name).slice(0,1);`

Comment: That works flawlessly! Thank you

Comment: That being said, there's definitely a more efficient way to do this rather than getting all results and then only returning the first one.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the comment answer (*of just using `const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, searchUrl, name).slice(0,1);`*) which is a quick hack, a more valid way would be to directly search just for the first instead of finding all and then using only the first.

- You could create a `findSingleMatch` that instead of `filter` uses the `find` method to find the first item in the array.
- In your case you should also not re-use the same RegExp object, since you are using `.test` which takes into account the previous index of a match when searching for the next (*see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Description*).
- finally you should put the `<a>` tag inside the `li` as it is invalid to put `<a>` directly under a `<ul>`

```js
function displayMatches() {
  const searchText = '20 pack';
  const searchUrl = document.querySelector('.custom-select').value;
  const place = findSingleMatches(searchText, searchUrl, name);

  if (place) {
    const regex = new RegExp(searchText);
    const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${searchText}</span>`);
    var shop = place.url.replace(/(centra)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
    var shop1 = place.url.replace(/(tesco)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
    var shop2 = place.url.replace(/(aldi)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
    var shop3 = place.url.replace(/(lidl)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
    var shop4 = place.url.replace(/(supervalu)|[^]/g, '$1').replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase());
    html = `
           <li> 
              <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank">
                  <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)} <br><br><sup>${shop} ${shop1} ${shop2} ${shop3} ${shop4}</sup></span>
                  <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100">
            </a>
         </li>
        `;
  } else {
    html = '<li> No Searches Found </li>'
  }
  suggestions.innerHTML = html;
};

function findSingleMatch(wordToMatch, searchUrl, name) {
    return name.find(place => {
        const regEx = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return regEx.test(place.name) && place.url.startsWith(searchUrl);
    });
}
```